# re store only one schema postgresql using pg_basebackup

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I have taken backup of postgresql DB using pg_basebackup. Is there a way I can restore only specific schema, not entire DB?

please advice, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no. What `pg_basebackup` does is create a complete copy of the database files (along with any WAL generated during the copying process). It is *all* of your databases at a file level.

So if you just want a single schema from a single database you need to restore the entire cluster and then use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` to create data-level backups of a single db / schema. There are options to filter down to a single schema or table.